# Combine Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have created two crystal reports files and i'm trying to combine these two file in the crystalreportviewer.

I need to display reports one after another. For example, if my first report has four pages then my second report should start from fifth page.

I have tried to use sub-report, but it's displaying second report within the first report. Is there any other way to display .rpt file one after another in crystalreportviewer?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can accomplish this by creating an empty report with **both** reports as subreports, one after another.